# Convert between any two primitive types in Java

Tags: java, types

In Java, would it be possible to implement a function that would take an object as input, and then convert the object to a type that is specified as a parameter?

I'm trying to implement a general-purpose type conversion function for primitive data types, but I don't know exactly where to start:

```
public static Object convertPrimitiveTypes(Object objectToConvert, String typeToConvertTo){
    //Given an object that is a member of a primitive type, convert the object to TypeToConvertTo, and return the converted object
}
```

For example, `convertPrimitiveTypes(true, "String")` would return the string `"true"`, and `convertPrimitiveTypes("10", "int")` would return the integer 10. If the conversion were not well-defined (for example, converting a boolean to an integer), then the method would need to throw an exception, and terminate the program.

Comment: (many) switch + (many) instanceof?

Comment: Your method takes an `Object` and returns an `Object`.  There's no primitives involved.

Comment: You do not specify an input type to convert from.

Comment: @Brandon The method does not specify a type to convert from. It specifies an object to convert, and a type to convert the object to.

Comment: By `Object` I'm assuming you mean for the primitive type's wrapper class to be sent to the function?

Comment: Is this used to process values coming from a web front-end by any chance ?

Comment: @JamesPoulson No, I'm just trying to find an easier way to convert between primitives, since it's not always easy to remember which function to use for each type conversion, since each type conversion function in the standard API has a different name. For the sake of syntactic clarity, I want to use a single function for all primitive type conversions.

Comment: Converting between primitives can be done with casting.

int i = 100;
long l = (long) i;
float f = (float) i;
char c = (char) i;

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have written this as

```
public static <T> T convertTo(Object o, Class<T> tClass) {
```

and it is possible if tedious.  If you don't care about efficiency you can can covert to a String and use "Class".valueOf(String) via reflection.

```
public static void main(String... ignore) {
    int i = convertTo("10", int.class);
    String s = convertTo(true, String.class);
    BigDecimal bd = convertTo(1.2345, BigDecimal.class);
    System.out.println("i=" + i + ", s=" + s + ", bd=" + bd);
}

private static final Map<Class, Class> WRAPPER_MAP = new LinkedHashMap<Class, Class>();

static {
    WRAPPER_MAP.put(boolean.class, Boolean.class);
    WRAPPER_MAP.put(byte.class, Byte.class);
    WRAPPER_MAP.put(char.class, Character.class);
    WRAPPER_MAP.put(short.class, Short.class);
    WRAPPER_MAP.put(int.class, Integer.class);
    WRAPPER_MAP.put(float.class, Float.class);
    WRAPPER_MAP.put(long.class, Long.class);
    WRAPPER_MAP.put(double.class, Double.class);
}

public static <T> T convertTo(Object o, Class<T> tClass) {
    if (o == null) return null;
    String str = o.toString();
    if (tClass == String.class) return (T) str;
    Class wClass = WRAPPER_MAP.get(tClass);
    if (wClass == null) wClass = tClass;
    try {
        try {
            return (T) wClass.getMethod("valueOf", String.class).invoke(null, str);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            return (T) wClass.getConstructor(String.class).newInstance(str);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new AssertionError(e);
    }
}
```

prints

```
i=10, s=true, bd=1.2345
```

Comment: OP asks about **primitives** which might mean that he does not want to use wrappers.

Comment: @PM77-1 The op's method takes an Object and returns an Object - there are no primitives in there.

Comment: Well, with autoboxing does he have that choice ? It would be a good idea to ask why primitives are sought :)

Comment: @assylias As input, the method should be able to take a primitive of any type, and it should be able to return a primitive of any type.

Comment: @AndersonGreen It will through auto (un-)boxing.

Comment: @assylias - Please look at his `convertPrimitiveTypes` sample which has a different signature altogether.

Comment: @PM77-1 This signature is preferable to the previous signature because it will be somewhat safer by forcing the user to consider the Class to convert to, rather than just saying "int" or "String"

Comment: @RyanAmos "String" is a good example for your argument given the class doesn't exist. It is `java.lang.String`

Comment: @PeterLawrey Yup, which means if you were to take a string argument, you'd have to have a massive map `string->class`, which would be annoying to write and would not be flexible enough to handle new circumstances. Your solution is much simpler, because I would bet the user knows what type they want at compile time.

Comment: Can I +2? :P This is one of the better mostly-code answers I've seen. You've got a test case in there, and all/most foreseeable problems are handled.

Comment: Didn't know int.class existed. Would have thought there was only Integer.class :p

Comment: @JamesPoulson You should give `void.class` and `Void.class` a try some time ;)

Comment: It appears that `convertTo("stuff", Boolean.class);` returns `false`, even though it shouldn't be possible to convert a string to a boolean. Converting a numeric value to a boolean doesn't make much sense either, but it still returns `false` for some reason.

Comment: That is how Boolean is parsed by the Java Libraries. It does a `"true".equalsCaseIgnore(string)` so if it is not true, it must be false ;)